# How to check if the page has content?

Tags: java, aem

I would like to avoid activating some page if its content is empty. I do this with some servlet as follow:

```
@SlingServlet(paths = "/bin/servlet", methods = "GET", resourceTypes = "sling/servlet/default")
public class ValidatorServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) {
        String page = "pathToPage";
        PageManager pageManager = request.adaptTo(PageManager.class);
        Page currentPage = pageManager.getPage(page);
        boolean result = pageHasContent(currentPage);
    }
```

Now how to check, if `currentPage` has content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that the following answer was posted in 2013 when CQ/AEM was a lot different to the current version. The following may not work consistently if used. Refer to [Tadija Malic's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66260025/1201244) for more on this.

The hasContent() method of the Page class can be used to check whether the page has content or not. It returns true if the page has **jcr:content** node, else returns false.

`boolean result = currentPage != null ? currentPage.hasContent() : false;`

In case you would like to check for pages that have not been authored, one possible way is to check if there are any additional nodes that are present under jcr:content.

```
Node contentNode = currentPage.getContentResource().adaptTo(Node.class);
boolean result = contentNode.hasNodes();
```

Comment: but currentPage.hasContent() returns ture even if the content is empty

Comment: When u mean content is empty, what are u actually referring to? The page is newly created and the author has not done any modifications to the page? Or something else?

Comment: yes empty means the page is newly created and the author has not done any think in it.

Comment: This is actually not a correct answer since an empty page can be created out of the template which will then have OOTB components provided. Since these components are not configured in advance, this page would still be considered as an empty page.

Comment: @TadijaMalić I agree. This was posted a long time ago when things were simple in AEM. I've updated the answer with the same note.

Answer (score 2):

I would create an OSGi service that takes a Page and walks its content tree according to the rules that you set to find out whether the page has meaningful content.

Whether a page has actual content or not is application-specific, so creating your own service will give you full control on that decision.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to [create a new page using the same template](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/PageManager.html#create(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and then iterating through the node list and calculating the hash of components (or their content depending on what exactly you want to compare). **Once you have the hash of an empty page template, then then you can compare any other page hash with that.**

Note: this solution needs to be adapted to your own use case. Maybe it is enough for you to check which components are on the page and their order, and maybe you want to compare their configurations as well.

```
private boolean areHashesEqual(final Resource copiedPageRes, final Resource currentPageRes) {
    final Resource currentRes = currentPageRes.getChild(com.day.cq.commons.jcr.JcrConstants.JCR_CONTENT);
    return currentRes != null && ModelUtils.getPageHash(copiedPageRes).equals(ModelUtils.getPageHash(currentRes));
}
```

Model Utils:

```
public static String getPageHash(final Resource res) {
    long pageHash = 0;

    final Queue<Resource> components = new ArrayDeque<>();
    components.add(res);

    while (!components.isEmpty()) {
        final Resource currentRes = components.poll();

        final Iterable<Resource> children = currentRes.getChildren();
        for (final Resource child : children) {
            components.add(child);
        }
        pageHash = ModelUtils.getHash(pageHash, currentRes.getResourceType());
    }

    return String.valueOf(pageHash);
}

/**
 * This method returns product of hashes of all parameters
 * @param args
 * @return int hash
 */
public static long getHash(final Object... args) {
    int result = 0;
    for (final Object arg : args) {
        if (arg != null) {
            result += arg.hashCode();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note: using Queue will consider the order of components as well.

This was my approach, but I had a very specific use case. In general, you would want to think if you really want to calculate the hash of every component on every page you want to publish since this will slow down the publishing process.
You can also compare hash in every iteration and break the calculation on the first difference.